# Application Crashes with 'jvm terminated. exit code=1'

Tags: java, jvm, crash-reports

Application intermittently crashes with error  'jvm terminated. exit code=1' as in screenshot
[Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI4zs.jpg)

It further creates an error log file (hs_err_pid) which reads

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x715c4ad6, pid=14580, tid=4648

JRE version: 6.0_21-b06
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.0-b16 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [COMCTL32.dll+0x54ad6]

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Could anyone suggest what does this error means and how to overcome this issue.

Comment: JRE 6.0_21, seriosly? This version is 10 years old, it has not been supported for a long time. Upgrade to a newer JRE, or, if it is a part of other software, contact the software vendor.

Comment: @apangin It is part of other software. We are looking to upgrade the software in 2021. But for now if you are able to help to fix the issue that would be great.